# Occupy a large number of TCP ports for testing purposes?

Tags: tcp, terminal

I would like to test what happens to some software when it cannot access any available TCP ports.

The simplest way for me to test this would be to simply occupy all available ports and then run the software.

Is there some simple way to occupy all ~65k TCP ports on mac? (I'd be very happy with some simple method that could be placed into a loop).

Sorry, it's an unusual question.

Comment: Just keep opening connections and not closing them.

Comment: @user207421 I just did some googling. I can see `nc -l 13370` will occupy port 13370. But does this mean I need to open some ~65k terminal windows to occupy all ports? Is there an easier way?